# Can't connect to Azure SQL Database in Jetbrains Datagrip but it works in SMSS

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, datagrip

I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL database using Datagrip (I'm on Linux) but am receiving a connection error. I tried installing Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SMSS) on a Windows machine and it worked fine.

This is a screenshot of the SMSS connection properties:

[image: SMSS connection properties]

And here is a screenshot of the Datagrip connection properties:

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you configured the SSL settings on Datagrip's SSH/SSL tab?

Comment: Can you try copying the JDBC connection string from Portal and change trustServerCertificate =true?  Ex: 
 `jdbc:sqlserver://{your_servername}.database.windows.net:1433;database={your_databasename};user={username}@{your_servername};password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`

Comment: please go to Advanced tab of data source properties and set parameter 'trustServerCertificate' to 'true'

Comment: Yes, setting trustServerCertificate to 'true' fixed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused if the Server name from the connection string does not match with the server name in the TLS certificate while validating.

When encrypt is set to true and `trustServerCertificate` is set to false, JDBC driver will validate the TLS certificate to ensure it is connecting to the correct server.

When ‘trustServerCertificate’ is set to true, JDBC driver will not validate in TLS certificate.

1. Get the JDBC Connection string from the portal.

[image]

2. Search for ‘trustServerCertificate’ and set it to “true”.

   ```
   jdbc:sqlserver://{your_servername}.database.windows.net:1433;database={your_databasename};user={your_username}@{your_servername};password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
   ```

[image]

Comment: does trust certificate setting to true gives meaning for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:// connections? I still get untrusted domain error.